# How can I prove that "If $M$ is contractible differentiable manifold, then $M$ is orientable?"

Tags: manifolds

If $M$ is a contractible differentiable manifold, then $M$ is orientable.

Comment: You haven't given any of your thoughts, @user

Comment: By the Poincare lemma, all closed forms are exact. Then by the natural projection $\pi: TM \to M$..,  compute the homology groups and show isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}.

Comment: @user- Please see FAQ page on how to ask a good question.

Comment: @Jaivir Baweja, I don't understand your hint about Poincare lemma. What homology groups are you computing?

Answer (score 3):

If $M$ is contractible, then any fibre bundle $E\rightarrow M$ is trivial. In particular, it means that the tangent space of $M$ and its cotangent space are trivial bundles.

Then, one can choose a global $n$-frame $(\xi_1,\cdots,\xi_n)$ of $T^\star M\rightarrow M$ and look at the $n$-form on $M$ given by $\omega = \xi_1\wedge \cdots \wedge \xi_n$.

It is a nowhere vanishing $n$-form, so it induces on orientation of $M$.